# Laravel 5.4 call js class from blade

Tags: javascript, laravel, ecmascript-6, laravel-blade

So i've upgraded a project i'm working on to 5.4 version and wants to take advantage of webpack.
so my problem is when creating a class in resources/js/application.js

```
class Wizard {
  InitSteps() {
     console.log('here');
}
```

if I'm calling it from within the js file it's working but if i'm calling it from the blade it's not..

so in my layout file there is something like that:

```
<body>
<!-- Body Contents -->

<script src="{{ mix('dist/js/application.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
@stack('scripts')
</body>
```

and in my blade i'm doing:

```
@push('scripts')
 <script>
  $(function(){
   let inst = new Wizard();
   inst.InitSteps();
  })
 </script>
@endpush
```

the error I'm getting is:
Uncaught ReferenceError: Wizard is not defined

I might get the es2015 wrong.., it's pretty new to me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're not able to use this is down to scope.

To put it in the Global (Window) scope you could do something like:

```
window.Wizard = class Wizard {
    InitSteps() {
        console.log('here');
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Did this answer your question, @ShahafAntwarg?